# calculating time difference between days

Tags: mysql, time

I have 4 columns:start date,end date, start time and end time. I need to find the difference i.e. endtime-start time. However the start date and end date need to be taken into account. Example: If I have start date = 7/6/2017 and start time =1:00 and end date -7/7/2017 end time = 2:00 then it is 25 hours..

I need to do this for all start and end dates within the past 1 week. Can someone help me with this. It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert your date and time to a Unix timestamp in seconds. Eg: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE("7/6/2017 1:00", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Then perform a basic substraction on both timestamps to get the time gap in seconds.

Also, as a general recommandation, it is best to convert your dates into the proper MySQL Datetime column type (better SQL support), or as a unix int timestamp (faster diffs), or as an ISO formatted string including the GMT data (better human readability, terrible lookups).

Comment: These are 4 different columns the date columns are in date format and time columns are of time datatype. it is not the same column containing both date and time.

Comment: You can use `CONCAT()` to create a single string.

Comment: could you give me an example? So you are saying i concatenate start dat e and start time and then do the same for end date and end time and then use timestampdiff?

Comment: This is pseudocode, but according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add `ADDDATE(your_date_date_format, INTERVAL your_time_string_format HOUR_MINUTE)` should return you a date with both days and seconds.